# Rails: Active Record has_many relation to always fetch only filtered results from initial query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a 'Courses' entity which has many 'Students'. I want to get courses where student name is like 'a%'. with a where query like:

```
courses = Course.students.where('...').to_a
```

Lets say I have only one course (A) and many students (S1, S2, S3...) from which only two students (S1, S2) having names starting with letter 'a'. So I want two courses as result: A -> S1,  A -> S2. Now when I iterate through courses the 'course.students' will be all students (Active Record lazy calls and collects all students), I want first course's students (courses.first.students) to only contain student S1 and second one to contain only student S2 in. Basically I want to let go of active record after the query call and have students that only the join query would have returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try

`result = Courses.includes(:students).where("students.name LIKE 'a%'").to_a`

You get 1 course, but if you next try

`result.first.students`

You get array of 2 students with name beginning 'a'